# How to stop a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014) from booting into recovery?

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, twrp, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

My Tablet is stuck in booting into a (not working) TWRP recovery. It shortly shows the Bootloader screen with "recovery booting ...", then the screen turns black and it reboots.

The LineageOS itself was booting fine. I tried all kinds of button combinitions to cancel recovery booting and get the system to boot, but it keeps booting into the broken recovery.

Is there any kind of hotkey to get the phone into a "boot to system" mode again?